# if data-progress="50" change data-progress-text

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress, pace.js, pace

I have a loader on my page and its html looks like this:

```
<div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="Loading 50/100" data-progress="50" style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px);">
```

I want to write a JS that can change the `data-progress-text` when the `data-progress is 50`
from `"Loading 50 / 100"` 
to `"Almost there!"`.

I do not know where to start and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if ( $('.pace-progress').attr('data-progress-text') == '50' ) {
(".pace-progress").attr("data-progress-text") == "Almost there!"}
```

Comment: What code have you tried?  Generally people like to help, but this appears you asking us to just do you work without you *doing anything yourself to get it to work*.

Comment: Right, so... when data-progress changes and becomes "50", update the other attribute. it really is that simple.

Comment: Ahahah you make it simple @KevinB.

Comment: I'll try a code and update the question @ErikPhilips.

Comment: What JavaScript, or jQuery, do you have that updates the `data-progress` attribute? Does it trigger an event of any kind that can be responded to?

Comment: There's a JS called pace.js that triggers that data-progress @DavidThomas. (https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/blob/master/pace.js)

Comment: Can you reproduce this on JSFiddle?

Comment: I tried @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc but it won't work without a huge external JS

Answer (score 0):

`==` is for comparing a value

`=` is for assigning a value

That said, since you are using the jQuery `attr` method you cannot assign a value like that. The method itself accepts a second argument to determine if it is a getter or a setter.

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) are pretty complete and you should definitely make use of them before asking questions

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval to check periodically for the value and update the corresponding attribute:

```
setInterval(fucntion(){
   if ( $('.pace-progress').attr('data-progress') == '50' )
      $(".pace-progress").attr("data-progress-text", "Almost there!");
}, 500);
```